# Output impedance matching for SN74lvc1t45

Tags: level-translation

We are using SN74LVC1T45 IC for level translation and we are feeding translated voltage through BNC connectors (75 ohms) to other peripherals, during this we want to achieve impedance matching of 75 ohms.

Comment: Two posts within 45 mins that are identical is not good.

Comment: So, what's the reason for impedance matching here? remember, "impedance" isn't a thing to achieve on its own, but for underlying technical reasons, like minimum transmission losses or maximum power transfer, but I think you might be forgetting that you're looking at a *driver* circuit.

Comment: Downvoted: I don't see how there can be a meaningful, helpful answer. The correct answer depends on the application. It might range from "you don't need to match the impedance" over parallel 75 ohm resistors at the receiver to active termination circuitry. The naming of a specific driver indicates to me that the you  have a specific application in mind, and this question is not supposed to be an open question of the kind "when and why do we need impedance matching and what are best-practice solutions for it?". Please give more background!

Comment: we are using SN74LVC1T45 IC for level translation and we are feeding translated voltage through BNC connectors (75 ohms) to other peripherals , during this we want to achieve impedance matching of 75 ohms.

Comment: why? That's not a reason! re-read my comment above.

Comment: The output from SN74LVC1T45 is high impedance, here we need to convert this high Z state to 75 ohm impedance for matching the video outputs

Comment: The only mention of "high impedance" in the datasheet is for when the IC is in the "disabled" state.  Other wise, it is actively driving its outputs.  I make the output impedance to be around 170 ohms.  It isn't given explicitly, but the datasheet gives typical output current at different voltages.

Comment: @mightybeard I concur with JRE, and also: If you think that this *driver* circuit (whose purpose is to drive something, i.e. have an appropriately low output impedance) has too high output impedance for your application, why did you choose the SN74LVC1T45? Please edit your question to explain exactly why you chose that transceiver, why you need bidirectional level translation, why you'd want to *match* your impedance (again, I doubt that's actually the case), and so on.

Comment: The LVC output impedance is quite low, but it depends on the output supply voltage, which you have kept secret.